# C# PostAsync with Parameter Error

Tags: c#, .net, json, rest

I am writing below code to call third party API but return error : Parameter error. I tested it in Postman can return response JSON result. Anyone can help what I am wrong.

```
namespace DemoApps
{
    class Program
    {
        static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        class P
        {
            public string language_id { get; set; }

            public string order_no { get; set; }

            public string token { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://medpro.vizzhost.com/linsy/eshop/admin/index.php?route=api/order/getByNo";

            string paramStr = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new P() {
                language_id = "1",
                order_no = "1707170018",
                token = "6b887489372f483792d490f5bc8104ef"
            });

            HttpContent content = new StringContent(paramStr, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            var response = httpClient.PostAsync(url, content)
                .Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(response.Result.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

[Program return error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6E97M.png)

[Postman running result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41aMD.png)

Comment: In your PostMan example, your are making the request as form data. Is that what the API requires for this endpoint? In your code, you are sending JSON.

Comment: In Postman, click "code" link and choose HTTP so you can see exactly what you need to recreate in c#.